# Is $U \cap \mathbb{R^3} \cong \mathbb{S^2}\times \mathbb{R^1} $

Tags: general-topology

If $U \subseteq\mathbb{S^3}$ is open and nonempty, Is $U \cap \mathbb{R^3} $ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S^2}\times \mathbb{R^1}$? how to imagine this?

Comment: Take $U$ to be a single point.

Comment: @Neal or empty :)

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: @Abel Well, the empty set can be confusing ... for example, every continuous map from the empty set to $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}^1$ is open and bijective!

Comment: @Neal That's true, but I think it is obvious nonetheless that $\varnothing\not\cong\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}^1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=\mathbb{S}^3$ and consider
$$U\cap\mathbb{R}^3 = \{(x,y,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4|x^2+y^2+v^2+w^2 = 1\}\cap\{(x,y,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4|w=0\}$$
$$ = \{(x,y,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4|w=0\mbox{ and }x^2+y^2+v^2=1\}\cong \mathbb{S}^2.$$

$\mathbb{S}^2$ does indeed contain some copies of $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{R}$ up to homeomorphism, but certainly not all open non-empty subsets are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{R}$.

I see you changed the sapce to be obtained to $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}$. From the above discussion it should be clear that this can never be accomplished.

If $U\subseteq\mathbb{S}^3$, then $U\cap\mathbb{R}^3\subseteq \mathbb{S}^3\cap\mathbb{R}^3\cong\mathbb{S}^2$. As $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}\not\subseteq\mathbb{S}^2$ no $U$ gives $U\cap\mathbb{R}^3\cong\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ok! this is very nice,, hence $U$ is simply connected :)  thank you very much :-)

Comment: That's not actually necessary now that I think of it. In fact the most obvious $U$'s for which it would work are $U=\{(x,y,v,w)\in\mathbb{S}^3|x\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}$ for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. These are simply connected I think.

Comment: I made big edit, makes more sense to be a question

Comment: but $S^2$ is simply connected for sure :)

Comment: and in your answer $U$ is the whole space $S^3$.. but it is just an open subset of it!!

Comment: Any space is an open subset of itself. You even explicitly wrote $U\subseteq\mathbb{S}^3$ instead of $U\subset\mathbb{S}^3$.

Comment: I updated the answer to suit your big edit.

Answer (score 1):

They may have wanted you to think of the 3-sphere as $\mathbb{R}^3$ plus a point. Then if $U$ is the sphere minus any other point, $U\cap\mathbb{R}^3$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}$.